# installing xlrd in to python3.6

Tags: python, xlrd

I have been trying to install xlrd into my computer but keep on popping out the below error msg.

> 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Version of Python is 3.6 in my computer

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you should be doing `python3 -m pip install xlrd`

This is because pip is a module within python not an actual command on your computer.